# How do I assign a default value for a no results sub query on a row by row basis?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables that contain user information, and a 'friends' relationship between users. To avoid requiring a relationship tagged as 'not friends' between each user and every other user i've chosen to define users with no relationship in the relationship table to not be friends.

However now i'm trying to implement a search function to assist users with added people as their friends, i'm attempted to return a list of other users who's names match a searched name; i'm also attempting to output the relationship status between the searching user and results users and i'm trying to use `IFNULL` to set the return value when no relationship exists.

The query I have written works fine for a single user, but when the sub query results return multiple users the `IFNULL` statement doesn't invoke on a row-by-row basis and instead is only invoked when the entire results table is empty.

Here are my tables:

```
user_table
+----+------------+-----------+
| id | first_name | last_name |
+----+------------+-----------+
| 1  | John       | Doe       |
| 2  | Jane       | One       |
| 3  | Jane       | Two       |
| 4  | Jane       | Three     |
+----+------------+-----------+

relationship_table
+-----------+-------------+--------------+
| sender_id | receiver_id | relationship |
+-----------+-------------+--------------+
| 1         | 2           | friends      |
| 3         | 1           | pending      |
+-----------+-------------+--------------+
```

I'm trying to generate the following when a search for `"jane"` is executed by the user John Doe.

```
results
+----+------------+-----------+--------------+
| id | first_name | last_name | relationship |
+----+------------+-----------+--------------+
| 2  | Jane       | One       | friends      |
| 3  | Jane       | Two       | pending      |
| 4  | Jane       | Three     | not friends  |
+----+------------+-----------+--------------+
```

Here is the query I have currently:

```
SELECT user_table.id, user_table.first_name, user_table.last_name, derived_table.relationship
FROM user_table, (
    SELECT IFNULL((type), 'not friends') AS relationship
    FROM relationship_table
    WHERE sender_id IN (
        SELECT id
        FROM user_table
        WHERE first_name LIKE 'jane%'
        OR last_name LIKE 'jane%'
        AND id != '1'
    )
    AND receiver_id = '1'
    OR receiver_id IN (
        SELECT id
        FROM user_table
        WHERE first_name LIKE 'jane%'
        OR last_name LIKE 'jane%'
        AND id != '1'
    )
    AND sender_id = '1'
)derived_table
WHERE first_name LIKE 'jane%'
OR last_name LIKE 'jane%'
AND user_table.id != '1'
```

This query is currently returning this for searches of `"jane"`:

```
+----+------------+-----------+--------------+
| id | first_name | last_name | relationship |
+----+------------+-----------+--------------+
| 2  | Jane       | One       | friends      |
| 2  | Jane       | One       | pending      |
| 3  | Jane       | Two       | friends      |
| 3  | Jane       | Two       | pending      |
| 4  | Jane       | Three     | friends      |
| 4  | Jane       | Three     | pending      |
+----+------------+-----------+--------------+
```

It's obvious to me the reason for this is because the entire result of the relationship sub query is being added to each set of user data, instead of matching up with the corresponding user.

Logic tells me that a join using the id would fix this problem, although as there is no consistency between which user sent a friendship request and thus no consistent id to join on... i'm not sure how to join them correctly.

P.S. I'm sure there is probably a way to do the check for relationships where you're the sender, or receiver better so any help with that would also be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to use `LEFT JOIN` if you want to get `NULL` when there's no match.

Comment: @Barmar If you'd like to post this as a solution i'll give you the correct answer. Thanks for the help.

Comment: It looks like you figured it out yourself. Post that as an answer, not as an update to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Left join between a table of all Janes, and a table of all of John's friends.

All Janes:

```
**Query**
SELECT user_table.id, user_table.first_name, user_table.last_name
FROM user_table
WHERE first_name LIKE 'jane%'
OR last_name LIKE 'jane%'
AND id != '1'

**Results**
+----+------------+-----------+
| id | first_name | last_name |
+----+------------+-----------+
|  2 | Jane       | One       |
|  3 | Jane       | Two       |
|  4 | Jane       | Three     |
+----+------------+-----------+
```

John's Friends:

```
**Query**
(
    SELECT relationship_table.sender_id AS id, relationship
    FROM relationship_table
    WHERE receiver_id = '1'
)
UNION
(
    SELECT relationship_table.receiver_id AS id, relationship
    FROM relationship_table
    WHERE sender_id = '1'
)

**Results**
+----+--------------+
| id | relationship |
+----+--------------+
|  2 | friends      |
|  3 | pending      |
+----+--------------+
```

Then combined:

```
**Query**
SELECT searched_users.id, searched_users.first_name, searched_users.last_name, IFNULL(users_friends.relationship, 'not friends') AS relationship
FROM (
    SELECT user_table.id, user_table.first_name, user_table.last_name
    FROM user_table
    WHERE first_name LIKE 'jane%'
    OR last_name LIKE 'jane%'
    AND id != '1'
)searched_users
LEFT JOIN (
    (
        SELECT relationship_table.sender_id AS id, relationship
        FROM relationship_table
        WHERE receiver_id = '1'
    )
    UNION
    (
        SELECT relationship_table.receiver_id AS id, relationship
        FROM relationship_table
        WHERE sender_id = '1'
    )
)users_friends
ON searched_users.id = users_friends.id

**Results**
+----+------------+-----------+--------------+
| id | first_name | last_name | relationship |
+----+------------+-----------+--------------+
| 2  | Jane       | One       | friends      |
| 3  | Jane       | Two       | pending      |
| 4  | Jane       | Three     | not friends  |
+----+------------+-----------+--------------+
```